# Upgrading from Elasticsearch 5.2.2 to 7.3

Tags: elasticsearch

We are currently using Elasticsearch 5.2.2 and planning to upgrade to 7.3. As the types are removed from version 7.0 onward, is converting type to index the best practice?

Comment: This question is answered in the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell yes

But if they are connected and have 1-1 1-many relationship you may want single document or nested ones.

There is no join between two indices